# How can I pass variables with space to cmake through CLI?

Tags: cmake

There is an option defined in a third party CMake file.

```
SET(PHYSX_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing ${GCC_WARNINGS}" CACHE INTERNAL "PhysX CXX")
```

I am trying to pass custom flags to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`:

```
cmake physx/sources/compiler/cmake -B build -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wno-restrict -Wno-class-memaccess"
```

Because I have space between the two GCC warning flags, the final result ends up breaking the string:

```
CXX_FLAGS = "-Wno-restrict ... # Quote is not closed
```

and I get an error about unterminated string

WHen I use no quotes around the flag CMake variable value:

```
cmake physx/sources/compiler/cmake -B build -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-Wno-restrict -Wno-class-memaccess
```

The final result ignores the value after space, which makes sense since space will be treated as a separate variable.

Is there something that I can do to set values with space into CMake variable?

Thanks @KamilCuk,

My problem was with the Python script that was triggering the commands. I had the following line in Python:

```py
subprocess.run(parsedCmdLine.split(' '), shell=platform.system() == 'Windows', cwd=x['sourceDir'])
```

Luckily, Python has a lexical utility module that resembles shell:

```py
import shlex

subprocess.run(shlex.split(parsedCmdLine.split), shell=platform.system() == 'Windows', cwd=x['sourceDir'])
```

Comment: `the final result ends up`  what is "the final result"? `I get an error about unterminated string` Please post the whole verbose (`make VERBOSE=1` or `cmake --build .. --verbose`) compilation command output including verbatim the error message to the question.

Comment: It is the output Makefile where flags are defined.

Comment: `I am trying to pass` Are you using Linux and Linux shell? `is the output Makefile` Do you inspect the generated Makefile files with an editor? Does running `make` works?

Comment: I am checking the final Makefile in an editor (I am basically debugging to find out what's goin on). The Makefile does run but it errors out because warnings are treated as errors and this library that I am trying to build fails because they throw warnings in GCC.

Comment: > Are you using Linux and Linux shell?

I have a custom Python script that generates the command line arguments and starts the process.

Comment: How are you "starting the process" and what comamnd line arguments are you passing _exactly_? Are you _sure_ that you did not include a _literal_ `"` inside command line arguments? Please post an [MCVE]. `because warnings are treated as errors` I do not know of such `make` argument, that would be odd. Please post the error message verbatim and the command you use. Does `make` invocation error, and with what message, or does the compiler invoked by make errors?

Comment: Here is the full command: `cmake  src/physx/source/compiler/cmake -B build -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wno-restrict -Wno-class-memaccess" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DPHYSX_ROOT_DIR=src/physx -DNV_USE_DEBUG_WINCRT=ON -DNV_USE_STATIC_WINCRT=OFF -DPXSHARED_INSTALL_PREFIX=vendor/ -DCMAKEMODULES_PATH=src/externals/cmakemodules -DPX_ROOT_LIB_DIR=lib -DPX_OUTPUT_LIB_DIR=src/build -DPX_OUTPUT_BIN_DIR=src/bin -DPXSHARED_PATH=src/pxshared -DTARGET_BUILD_PLATFORM=linux -DPX_GENERATE_STATIC_LIBRARIES=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=vendor`, I just spawn shell process and call cmake.

Comment: `spawn shell process` How do you "spawn shell process"? Please post the python code, if it is used. Does invoking the command from the command line causes the same error?

Comment: The error that I am getting when passing the variable with quotes is triggered by shell that calls CMake due to quotes: `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Comment: `subprocess.run(parsedCmdLine.split(' '), shell=platform.system() == 'Windows', cwd=x['sourceDir'])`

Comment: `parsedCmdLine.split(' '),` how do you think this works?..... `/bin/sh:` that's an error from shell. Not from cmake, not from make, not from compiler. Please include all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the whole -D parameter, like:

```
$ cmake ../ '-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/baiyanh/arena/cmake/tut/build
```

Then the compile looks like:

```
$ cmake --build . -v
...
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tut.dir/tut.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer   -o CMakeFiles/tut.dir/tut.cpp.o -c /home/baiyanh/arena/cmake/tut/tut.cpp
...
```